# Showing that a limit does not exists...

Tags: real-analysis, limits

**Question**: Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function with $f(0, 0) = 0$. Assume that there exists a constant $M > 0$ such that $||\nabla f(x, y)|| \leq M$, for all $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

1. Prove that $|f(x, y)| \leq M \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, for all $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.
2. Suppose further that $\nabla f(x, y) = (1, 2)$, for all $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Prove that

$$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{f(x, y)}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$$

does not exist.

**Answer**:

1. This is easily shown by the Mean Value Theorem and an application of the Cauchy Schwarz inequality.
2. This is where I am stuck. I know that

$$\bigg|\frac{f(x, y)}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\bigg| \leq M,$$

but not sure how to use this. Also, am not seeing how the gradient always being $(1, 2)$ is useful. I have tried taking different sequences $\{(x_k, y_k)\}$ that tend to zero, but haven't had much luck their either. Any suggestions?

Comment: The gradient being $(1,2)$ for all $(x,y)$ is a very strong condition. That tells you that $f(x,y)=x+2y+c$. Since we are also assuming $f(0,0)=0$. Then $f(x,y)=x+2y$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose two differentiable functions, $f_{1}(x, y)$ and $f_{2}(x, y)$, have the same gradient.  It follows that their difference,
$$
f_{1} - f_{2},
$$
has gradient zero, hence is constant.  It follows that the gradient determines the function up to an additive constant.  Consequently,
$$
f(x, y) = x + 2y + c,
$$
where $c$ is some constant.  However, we are also told that
$$
f(0, 0) = 0,
$$
so $c = 0$.